# .NET MVC Unable to Deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest

I am using the results from [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) on the response below from a GET request within my MVC Model:

```
{
  "Id": 1111111,
  "CreateLocation": "xxxxxxxxEZ-V12",
  "ConstituentType": {
    "Description": "Individual",
    "Id": 1,
    "Inactive": false,
    "ConstituentGroup": {
      "Description": "Individual",
      "Id": 1,
      "Inactive": false
    }
  },
  "DisplayName": "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx",
  "FirstName": "xxxxxxxx",
  "Inactive": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Description": "Active",
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "InactiveReason": null,
  "LastActivityDate": "2016-10-16T02:32:15Z",
  "LastName": "xxxxxxxx",
  "MailIndicator": {
    "Description": "(none)",
    "Id": 3,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "EmarketIndicator": {
    "Description": "(none)",
    "Id": 3,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "MiddleName": "",
  "NameStatus": {
    "Description": " ",
    "Id": 1,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "OriginalSource": {
    "Description": "Test Test",
    "Id": 4,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "PhoneIndicator": {
    "Description": "(none)",
    "Id": 3,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "Prefix": {
    "Description": "",
    "Id": -1,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "Gender": null,
  "Suffix": {
    "Description": "",
    "Id": -1,
    "Inactive": false
  },
  "Salutation": {
    "BusinessTitle": null,
    "CreatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:52Z",
    "CreateLocation": "xxxxxxxxEZ-V12",
    "Constituent": {
      "Id": 8775975
    },
    "CreatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Id": 912925,
    "DefaultIndicator": true,
    "EnvelopeSalutation1": "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx",
    "EnvelopeSalutation2": "",
    "Label": true,
    "UpdatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:52.937Z",
    "UpdatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
    "LetterSalutation": "xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx",
    "SalutationType": {
      "Description": "Default",
      "Id": 0,
      "Inactive": false
    },
    "EditIndicator": true,
    "IsFromAffiliation": false
  },
  "Address": {
    "Id": 9781315,
    "AffiliatedConstituent": null,
    "AltSalutationType": {
      "Description": "Default",
      "Id": 0,
      "Inactive": false
    },
    "AddressType": {
      "Description": "Home Address",
      "Id": 3,
      "Inactive": false
    },
    "City": "Brooklyn",
    "CreatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:52Z",
    "CreateLocation": "xxxxxxxxEZ-V12",
    "CreatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Constituent": {
      "Id": 8775975
    },
    "DeliveryPoint": "",
    "EndDate": null,
    "GeoArea": 35,
    "Inactive": false,
    "Label": true,
    "UpdatedDateTime": "2016-09-21T16:00:46.497Z",
    "UpdatedBy": "NCOA$STD",
    "Months": "YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "NcoaAction": 3,
    "NcoaSession": 9,
    "PostalCode": "12121212",
    "PostalCodeFormatted": "11205-2348",
    "PrimaryIndicator": true,
    "StartDate": null,
    "State": {
      "Description": "New York",
      "StateCode": "NY",
      "Id": 51,
      "Inactive": false,
      "Country": {
        "Description": "USA",
        "Id": 1,
        "Inactive": false
      }
    },
    "Street1": "11 Fadeaddress Ave",
    "Street2": null,
    "Street3": null,
    "Country": {
      "Description": "USA",
      "Id": 1,
      "Inactive": false
    },
    "EditIndicator": true,
    "IsFromAffiliation": false
  },
  "ElectronicAddress": {
    "Address": "test@test.edu",
    "AffiliatedConstituent": null,
    "AltSalutationType": null,
    "CreatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:53Z",
    "CreateLocation": "xxxxxxxxEZ-V12",
    "CreatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
    "Constituent": {
      "Id": 8775975
    },
    "Id": 9781317,
    "ElectronicAddressType": {
      "Description": "Home Email",
      "Id": 1,
      "Inactive": false,
      "IsEmail": true
    },
    "EndDate": null,
    "AllowHtmlFormat": true,
    "Inactive": false,
    "UpdatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:53.03Z",
    "UpdatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
    "AllowMarketing": true,
    "Months": "YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "PrimaryIndicator": true,
    "StartDate": null,
    "EditIndicator": true,
    "IsFromAffiliation": false,
    "IsEmail": true
  },
  "PrimaryPhoneNumbers": [
    {
      "Address": {
        "Id": 9781315,
        "AddressType": {
          "Description": "Home Address",
          "Id": 3,
          "Inactive": false
        }
      },
      "AllowTelemarketing": true,
      "DayEveningIndicator": " ",
      "Constituent": {
        "Id": 8775975
      },
      "Id": 9781316,
      "Inactive": false,
      "PhoneNumber": "11111111",
      "PhoneFormatted": "(917) 561-0972     ",
      "PhoneSearch": "11111111",
      "PhoneType": {
        "Description": "Phone 1",
        "Id": 1,
        "Inactive": false
      },
      "CreatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
      "CreateLocation": "xxxxxxxxEZ-V12",
      "CreatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:53Z",
      "UpdatedDateTime": "2016-05-21T16:47:53.027Z",
      "UpdatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
      "EditIndicator": true
    }
  ],
  "CreatedDateTime": "2015-05-23T14:03:23Z",
  "CreatedBy": "xxxxxxxx",
  "UpdatedDateTime": "2016-10-16T02:32:15.527Z",
  "UpdatedBy": "dbo     ",
  "SortName": "xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx",
  "Affiliates": [],
  "ProtectionType": null
}
```

But when I try to deserialize the JSON output and return the results to my View with

```
//Storing the response details recieved from web api   
var json = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

//Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Constituent>>(json);
```

I get the error **Cannot deserialize the current JSON object...because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array...that can be deserialized from a JSON object.**

Comment: The `PrimaryPhoneNumbers` node for example is an array (starts and ends with `[ ]`. If it not a List or Array in your `Constituent` class you will get that error.

Comment: I noticed that too but that's part of what the GET request gives me. It is set as `public List<PrimaryPhoneNumber> PrimaryPhoneNumbers { get; set; }` in the Model.

Comment: That should be ok. `Affiliates` is an array also. Did you get that one also?

Comment: Yes and that is set as `public List<object> Affiliates { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example response is a single object, not an array. I can't see your implementation of Constituent but assume it matches that definition?

In which case you should be able to deserialize the single result (rather than a list) using:

```
EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Constituent>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm now getting **The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TestRest.Models.Constituent', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestRest.Models.Salutation]'.**

Comment: That must be happening with code that uses the EmpInfo variable (adds to a dictionary)? You just need to be consistent with your use of single vs. collection of instances.

Comment: Do you have @model List<Constituent> at the top of your view? You need to decide whether you're displaying a single item or a list and ensure your JSON, model and view all reflect that.

Comment: Do you have @model List<Constituent> at the top of your view? You need to decide whether you're displaying a single item or a list and ensure your JSON, model and view all reflect that.

Comment: I have `@model IEnumerable<TestRest.Models.Constituent>` currently at the top of my view. Does that mean I'm looking for a list as opposed to a single item?

Comment: That's right, yeah. If you do @model TestRest.Models.Constituent instead then it should work, but your view will then be showing properties of a single instance

Comment: It worked once I changed the header in my view from `@model IEnumerable<TestRest.Models.Constituent>` to `@model TestRest.Models.Constituent` because as you pointed out **the JSON response is a single object and not an array**.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JSONtext)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where is JSONtext coming from?

Comment: JSONText is jsonString.. any json will be deserialized...the parameter name is not important

Comment: I'm now getting the error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestRest.Models.Constituent>'**

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing but you are doing it wrong...I just tested my code with your json and it works fine. Try this in a separated project.

`using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string objJson = @"  INSERT YOUR JSON STRING HERE ";

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(objJson);
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful but I'd like to focus on using the HttpClient method because for REST purposes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190120/discussion-between-merak-marey-and-gabed123).